Why the Sun is reflected by rivers and lakes in video of NASA ISS live, but not from sea or oceans?
When I see many ISS live video, the Sun reflection is intense and defined on terrain, passing over a rivers or lakes. At the end of coasts, the reflection in the water sea become like vanished, or in form of low bright halo. Why ??!!

Wild guess: lakes and rivers are more likely to be calm and flat, the sea is more likely to be rough and choppy.

I think that's correct -- IIRC the size of waves that can exist in a body of water are proportional to the size of the body's narrowest dimension. A river is relatively flat on a large scale, while the ocean is relatively bumpy.

You should include an example in your question.  This one does show a specular reflection from the ocean: https://www.nasa.gov/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/eo_pe_iss062e117852_sm.png

@GregMiller and add a modifier like "usually" or "frequently"

Also the contrast with backgroung can have an effect. The land surrounding rivers and lakes looks much darker when we see the sun reflection. But an ocean reflection mostly haven't such contrast objects. It would be interesting to compare reflection perception from the ocean when it reaches a shore, a river delta or an archipelago. Maybe it's mostly just a perception, like this famous example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checker_shadow_illusion

@DarthPseudonym Only slow flowing rivers are relatively flat on a large scale but not the fast flowing ones. But also the Salish sea between Vancouver island and the mainland is relatively flat on a large scale. Its surface looks like a sweat water valley.

I don't think it's true that you get zero shiny reflections (aka specular highlights) on the ocean, but they do seem less intense.
I think there are two things going on. First, the ocean has more and bigger waves, so it is rougher. The waves reflect light in different directions, making the overall reflection more diffuse. That's not enough to eliminate specular highlights on the ocean, but they are more spread out.
The second thing is that the land around the lakes provides contrast. When the light hits the lake just right, it shows up as a bright reflection surrounded by darker land. In the ocean, there's no sharp cutoff between the brightest part of the reflection and a surrounding darker area.

Captions from ISS EHDC6 camera live 26 Dec 2024, different reflections:
Clear little spot Vs. huge halo in sea or ocean.



You may be referring to opposition surge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposition_surge which is bright over textured terrain (trees, crops) but disappears over smooth terrain such as water bodies.

See also What makes materials on the Moon look so different when the sun is high?

Please link to the effect you are referring to. Specular reflections have equal angles of incidence and reflection, while opposition surge is at the antisolar point, so it is easy to differentiate the two effects if the video clip in question is available.

I think that the OP might actually be asking about the difference between different types of bodies of waters; small: "rivers and lakes" vs. large: "sea". Also, "Heiligenschein" seems to be related to the optics of dew drops on surfaces, or water droplets in air. When it's related to textured (but dry) surfaces it's called shadow hiding and in the case of the Moon, opposition surge

...and in radar, a very different phenomenon: coherent backscattering

@uhoh ,,, you are correct about heiligenshjein vs shadow hiding. Answer corrected.

yay! It's quite an interesting topic. If we only had an Optics and Photonics SE site, we could dig deeper.
